# What is the autocorrelation equivalent of the spectrogram called?

Tags: autocorrelation, spectrogram, periodic

I'm very knowledgeable about the differences between the Fourier transform, and the autocorrelation; mainly that one converts the time domain to the frequency domain, and the other finds periodicities (regardless of spectral composition). And I'm not asking what either does, or how to perform them.

My question is, when one does the equivalent of STFT (short-time Fourier transform) to produce a spectrogram, but with overlapping windowed autocorrelations, what is the result called? The result is very similar, but with the frequency axis kind of inverted and scaled to give the periodic lag, and the amplitude axis is now the correlation.

Comment: Sliding window autocorrelation?

Comment: That's descriptive, but I'll see if anyone else has suggestions.

Comment: Another term I've seen used is "correlogram." In your case we might call it "autocorrelogram." Here's an implementation: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15299-windowed-cross-correlation--corrgram- (I can convert these comments to an answer if it's acceptable.)

Comment: I don't think autocorrelogram is descriptive enough, as it is *mostly synonymous with correlogram - which just means a graph of the correlation. There is no implication of the 3d dimension (i.e., time, with the sliding windows).